# Is it possible to change an iframe's element position to be out of the iframe

Tags: css, iframe

I have an iframe on a page, and in this iframe page there is a button, I want to move the button's position to out of the iframe (visually). Is it possible.

```
----(want to move the button to here)
<div>
--- other elements----
</div> 
-------iframe---------
-                  ---
----the menu button---
-                  ---
----------------------
```

Can it be done by just by tweaking the CSS？

Comment: May be you can try `position:absolute;`  reply me if I am wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to move the button with CSS outside the ´<iframe>`? If so, what happened? What else have you tried?

Comment: @venkateshwar  it does not work

Comment: @Henrik basically, i tried the position:absolute with top:-50;. I can not move the buttom it is inside the iframe due to the layout used in my work.

Comment: Then you need to be able to change the DOM with (for instance) Javascript, grab the button from the `<iframe>`, remove it and then insert it into the outlying `<body>` (not the iframes) for positioning. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is quite easy to learn on how to manipulate the DOM. There are tons of tutorials etc out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the iFrame content is considered part of the page DOM or if it is it might be blocked for security reasons (I could be wrong here) - so I would be very surprised if this works.

One very hacky, dirty, 'gosh I'm ashamed' way around this is to screen scrape the page the iFrame is in and with your server side (if any) technology insert the parsed scraped content into your page. The new content will be part of the DOM and you can CSS and jQuery stuff about.

I can't really recommend this technique though.